# How to release an Image.Source to update the image in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to update an Image.Source property to the same file path but updated. I am using a method to set the Source property.

**METHOD:**

```
    void setImageSource(string file)
    {
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        Uri imageSource = new Uri(file);
        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        image.UriSource = imageSource;
        image.EndInit();

        ssPreview.Source = image;
    }
```

In first set of the source has no problem. But when I call this method second time, it throws an error on the `ssPreview.Source = image` line. The error says `cannot access file because it is being used by another process`.

I can't fix this problem. How to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message indicates that the image file is still open while you are trying to create a BitmapImage from it. This means that you didn't close it after updating.

---

Besides that, a safer method to load a BitmapSource from a file would be to use a `FileStream` instead of an Uri, like shown below. This definitely avoids any image URI caching that may be done by WPF.

```
private static BitmapSource LoadImage(string path)
{
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
        bitmap.EndInit();
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Or shorter:

```
private static BitmapSource LoadImage(string path)
{
    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        return BitmapFrame.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
    }
}
```